# How mirages forms and how diamonds sparkle?

Tags: optics, visible-light

1. How [mirages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage) forms?
2. How diamonds sparkle?
3. What is major cause happening for it and can you explain with examples?

Comment: These are two completely separate questions. We encourage one question per post. Could you split?

Comment: Did you look for the answer in places like Wikipedia before posting here? What did you learn, and what do you still not understand? We prefer questions that demonstrate some effort on the part of the person asking.

Comment: For info on mirages [see this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mirage+is%3Aquestion). There isn't a precise duplicate to your Q1, but if reposted it would probably be closed on the grounds of insufficient effort.

Answer (score 1):

To make you simply understand the diamonds are cut in specific shape allowing light to come out of its edge only. The light can enter but due to its refractive index the light is bent and can come out of its edge only so we see it sparkling.Also,
 **refractive index = angle of sine of incident ray / angle of sine of refracted ray**

Also
 the mirage are similar you can get more info here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkkqUh_zaRY

Comment: It is related to total internal reflection